# Trying to use Shopify's Draggable module with svelte, but no luck

Tags: javascript, shopify, draggable, svelte

Any tips on getting NPM modules to work with svelte? I'm trying to use Shopify's draggable module, but no luck. It seems to import fine, but the drag and drop will not work. No errors, no messages, no nothing.

My main attempt has been based on this example: https://codepen.io/RoyCurtis/pen/EevgbB

Specifically, I've tried to implement that example as follows in the App.svelte file:

```
import Draggable from '@shopify/draggable';

let dropzones = document.querySelectorAll('.dropzone');

let droppable = new Draggable.Droppable(
  dropzones,
  {
    draggable: '.draggable',
    dropzone:  '.dropzone',
    mirror:    { constrainDimensions: true }
  }
);
```

Here's my Github repo of my current attempt. As mentioned above, I get no errors from my devo server, nor any in the browser. The page/app loads and displays fine, but there is no drag-and-drop functionality.

https://github.com/mundek/svelte-drag-drop

Answer (score 2):

I failed to recognize that the draggable-related code can't attach to DOM elements that haven't mounted yet.

A kind soul on the svelte Discord channel shared a fix, and now the app works as planned:

https://github.com/mundek/svelte-drag-drop/commit/abeac03d869005f3d7485dd9d7d289709c8b2f65

Answer (score 0):

When using `document.querySelectorAll('.dropzone');` you are making the call before the DOM is loaded, therefore you are getting back an empty NodeList which is expected behavior even though that's not what you want.

You need to use svelte's onMount wrapper which will run your code after the DOM is loaded, and you'll get the behavior you want.

```
import { onMount } from 'svelte';
import Draggable from '@shopify/draggable';

onMount( ()=>{

  let dropzones = document.querySelectorAll('.dropzone');

  let droppable = new Draggable.Droppable(
    dropzones,
    {
      draggable: '.draggable',
      dropzone:  '.dropzone',
      mirror:    { constrainDimensions: true }
    }
  );

});
```

I see you already posted your own answer, yet it doesn't clarify the answer for other users who visit this question.